# Induction and trig identity question.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am in need of help for this question that I am stuck on, my work so far is this.

$s(n) = ( \cos (\theta) + i \sin (\theta)）^n = \cos (n \theta) +i \sin (n \theta)$

s(1) = true

$s(k)=( \cos (\theta) + i \sin (\theta)）^k= \cos (k\theta) +i \sin (k\theta)$

S(k+1) =.......(too many steps so i'll go to step where i am stuck)

= $$\cos (k \theta) \cos (\theta) -  \sin (k \theta) \sin \theta) + i(\sin (\theta) \cos(\theta)+\sin(k\theta)\cos(\theta))$$

From that step I am so confused because my book jumps from that step to $\cos ((k+1)\theta) + i \sin ((k+1)\theta)$ which is the RHS of the k+1 step. No steps were shown, the book just abruptly wrote it equal that and I don't know how it is. Can someone explain

Comment: It comes from just foiling out the new expansion and then collecting the real and imaginary parts, and then using the sum formulas for cosine and sine.

Comment: Anyway you can show me this?

Comment: The easiest way to prove that is using Euler's identity: $$e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$$

Comment: @user3718584: it's just $\sin(a+b)=\sin a\cos b+\sin b\ cos a$ and the similar formula for cosine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we establish that the identity holds for $n=1$. Here we have $$(\cos(\theta) + i \sin(\theta))^1 = \cos(1\cdot \theta) + i \sin(1\cdot \theta)$$

It is clear that it is true in this case. Now we assume this holds for some $n \ge 1$. That is we have already "checked" that $$(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))^n = \cos(n\theta) + i \sin(n\theta)$$ holds for all integers up to some $n$.

Now we want to show it holds for the next integer, $n+1$. This is where we apply our assumption.

$$(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))^{n+1} = (\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))^n(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)) = (\cos(n\theta) + i \sin(n\theta))(\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta))$$
$$=(\cos(n\theta)\cos(\theta)-\sin(n\theta)\sin(\theta))+i(\sin(n\theta)\cos(\theta)+\cos(n\theta)\sin(\theta))$$
$$=\cos((n+1)\theta) + i \sin((n+1)\theta)$$

Thus we have shown by induction that the formula holds for all $n=1,2,3,...$.

Comment: Ho do you get from second last step to lsst step?

Comment: That is the sum identity for cosine and sine respectively.

Answer (score 0):

$$(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta )^{k+1} = (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta )(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta )^k =$$
$$= (\cos \theta + i \sin \theta ) (\cos k \theta + i \sin k \theta ) =$$
$$= (\cos \theta \cos k \theta - \sin \theta \sin k\theta) + i (\cos \theta \sin k \theta + \sin \theta \cos k \theta) =$$
$$= \cos(k\theta + \theta)+ i \sin(k\theta + \theta) = 
\cos((k+1)\theta)+ i \sin((k+1)\theta)$$

You use [these formulas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities).